# YouTube OEmbed service doesn't work well for video url with playlist and index query param

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, oembed

Recently, I tried to use OEmbed service to get iframe code for the video url with playlist query param, but OEmbed service us the iframe code which hasn't the same video as i asked.

Here is the video url with playlist query param:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B2PhzzVwRM4&index=5&list=PLXtHYVsvn_b-7onG7XS6HN7v9XlVEFvJL

Here is YouTube OEmbed service url for getting iframe code of the video:
https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https%3a%2f%2fwww.youtube.com%2fwatch%3fv%3dB2PhzzVwRM4%26index%3d5%26list%3dPLXtHYVsvn_b-7onG7XS6HN7v9XlVEFvJL

But OEmbed service return me the iframe code which turn out not the same video as I ask.

Here is iframe code returned:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLXtHYVsvn_b-7onG7XS6HN7v9XlVEFvJL      is not the same video as   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B2PhzzVwRM4&index=5&list=PLXtHYVsvn_b-7onG7XS6HN7v9XlVEFvJL

Could anyone help me to take a look how can I get the right video through YouTube OEmbed sevice?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to place the index number of the actual video from the playlist that is why you always end up calling the first video of the playlist.

Upon checking the actual playlist, there are 9 videos. Since the 5th video seems to be the one you are calling, you must include "index=4" since the numbering will start at 0 from the first video. Try the link below:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?index=4&list=PLXtHYVsvn_b-7onG7XS6HN7v9XlVEFvJL

This link should return the actual video that you need.